# Taping or not unexposed wall joints

Tags: drywall, joints, cement-board, taping

I have some joints between drywall and drywall and also drywall and cementboard that will not be exposed because they are behind cabinets. Do I still need to tape them together? Does taping provide any structural function or is it just for the looks?

Answer (score 2):

Taping creates a fire barrier if there ever happened to be a fire in your wall a non taped joint could be a problem.

Comment: But if no fire, no one can ever know whether it is taped or not

Comment: This is true but if is a big word for the disaster that could happen.

Comment: Taping also blocks roaches and other insects.

Answer (score 0):

Taping provides a moisture barrier and an insect barrier. Sure, no one would know...until some event brings it to their attention.